# Microphone permissions for Chome packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm writing a packaged app for Chrome that uses [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) to access the user's microphone. The permission dialog for microphone access surfaces when I request access.

In a Chrome packaged app, can I somehow do away with that popup? Perhaps via asking for mic/media permissions beforehand?

For a web view, we can handle the `permissionrequest` event. Is there something similar we can do for packaged apps?

I couldn't find [the permission to specify](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) in the manifest for packaged Chrome apps.

Answer (score 0):

So ... "audioCapture" and "videoCapture" are actually valid permission strings to use for manifests in packaged Chrome apps ...

They grant audio and video getUserMedia permissions to your packaged app.

except Google didn't document this in
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

sigh ...

Comment: Those permissions might not be valid for extensions. They are included in the permissions list for apps: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions